# Determine whether Wurmple will evolve into Silcoon or Cascoon

Tags: pokemon-go

Wurmple has two evolutionary paths, via Silcoon to Beautifly and via Cascoon to Dustox.

[image: Evolutionary path Wurmple]

In the original games this is based on [Personality Value](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Personality_value#Wurmple.27s_evolution). There is no sign this is yet in Pokemon Go, so how is is determined in this game?

Comment: So far it seems it is purely RNG. [Sylph Road](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/7jbsh8/evolving_wurmple_crowd_sourcing/) made some researches, and so far it seems that the day/night cycle, weather, stats and genders doesn't have any effect on it at least. I'd rather not post it as an answer though as nothing is sure yet.

Comment: @Isuka Indeed. Moveset is also debunked. Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: Can we rule out the nickname technique (which Eevee uses to decide its evolutions) applying to Wurmple?

Comment: @Kozaky [Some users](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/7ivnzy/needs_more_testing_wurmple_nicknames_for_evolution/) are making some researches on it right now, but have yet to find any working nickname.

Comment: I feel like pointing out "Personality Value" basically means random. It's determined randomly, it can't be viewed without hacking, nor reverse engineered from visible stats (like with IVs). Maybe someone will now argue that back in Gen 3, there were things that depended on the PID, so it could technically be reverse engineered in part, but that's no longer the case and Go seems to be based on the most recent main series games, barring availability of different species. Since it was purely random in the main series, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be purely random in Go, too.

Comment: I just want to share what happened to me today. An egg hatched, it was a Wurmple. I evolved it right away and it evolved into a Cascoon. It was raining and it was during the day. Maybe this information with help someone else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are the a few articles online that come up talking about how to Evolve Wurple to either Silcoon of Cascoon. As it appears, there seems to be no way of dictating what it will evolve to at the moment:

## Extracts / Passages from text

> In Pokémon Go, Eevee's evolution into Flareon, Jolteon or Vaporeon could be determined by giving your Eevee the respective nickname.
>
> Unfortunately this is not the case with Wurmple and nicknames have no effect.
>
> At the moment it appears that Wurmples evolve randomly in Pokémon Go which means you need to catch as many as you can to get the evolution you want.

~an extract from [The Sun's article](https://www.thesun.co.uk/tech/5125577/pokemon-go-latest-news-update-wurmple-evolution-eevee/)

> DOES WURMPLE’S EVOLUTION DEPEND ON GENDER?
>
> Looking at Dustox and Beautifly, it’s easy to think that Wurmple’s gender will determine its evolution, but that wasn’t the case in Pokémon Ruby and Sapphire. It’s also not the case in Pokémon Go .
>
> User VarecnaV89 asked whether evolving Wurmple with different gender and they confirmed that they received the same Pokémon.
>
> DOES TIME AFFECT IT?
>
> When Gen 2 came to Pokémon Go, Eevee’s new evolutions, Umbreon and Espeon, could be obtained by evolving Eevee during either the night or day. With Dustox being a moth, many believed the time of day affected Wurmple’s evolution. However, that turned out to be untrue as well, as trainers in this thread determined.
>
> IS IT A NICKNAME TRICK?
>
> Pokémon Go trainers found that evolving Eevee into Flareon, Jolteon or Vaporeon could be determined by its nickname. The nicknames used were the based on the Pokémon anime, so some trainers believed nicknaming their Wurmple after trainers who used them in the anime would do the trick. However, trainers tried naming Wurmple May to get a Silcoon, and Jesse for Cascoon, and that didn’t work.
>
> DOES WURMPLE’S IVs DETERMINE ITS EVOLUTION?
>
> Tyrogue is another Pokémon from the Johto region with an unusual evolution, which could evolve into either Hitmonlee, Hitmontop or Hitmonchan depending on the Tyrogue’s IVs. Naturally, this led trainers to test whether Wurmple’s IVs
>
> User Technovoid200 tested this theory, and thought they were on to> something, but eventually concluded IVs didn’t determine Wurmple’s evolution.
>
> Unfortunately, it looks like Wurmple evolves randomly in Pokémon Go, so be sure to catch as many as you can to get the desired evolution. In the meantime, let us know whether you like Dustox or Beautifly better in the comments section below

~ <del>Extract</del> Passage from [Player One's article](http://www.player.one/pokemon-go-gen-3-update-wurmple-evolution-122286)

## Conclusion

#### No, it doesn't look like it, but there is no proof to show it. We are not certain, but research shows that there is probably no way to do so.